# Knex operation throwing exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2013, knex.js

I'm trying to write an `UPDATE` statement with Knex.

The SQL I'd like to output is:

```
UPDATE customers SET "month_value" = "src"."month_value", "modified" = NOW() FROM ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM("month_value"), 0) AS month_value FROM "customer_products" WHERE "active" = true AND "customer_id" = 111781 ) src WHERE "id" = 111781
```

This is my JavaScript so far:

```
db.knex.table('customers')
      .where('id', '=', ':customerId')
      .from(db.sequelize.knex.raw('(' +
        'SELECT' +
        'COALESCE(SUM("month_value"), 0) AS month_value' +
        'FROM "customer_products"' +
        'WHERE "active" = true' +
        'AND "customer_id" = ?' +
        ') AS src' +
        'WHERE "id" = :customerId', [customerId]))
      .update({'month_value': src.month_value,
               'modified': NOW(),
              })
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
{"message":"ApiErrorMiddleware ReferenceError: src is not defined","level":"info"}
{"message":"UnknownErrorMiddleware ReferenceError: src is not defined","level":"info"}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You are trying to do many complicated things at once, without first trying to learn each feature separately. Now there are some very fundamental problems trying to access for example src.month_value as javascript object when it should be passed as raw SQL to database and same for tryingin to call nonexisting function NOW()  (unless you have implemented that by yourself). And using named bindings (`:customerId`) are also used wrong. So try to learn first basics with simpler examples and by looking output of `toSQL()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
db.sequelize.knex.table('customers')
  .where('id', '=', ':customerId')
  .from(db.sequelize.knex.raw('('
    + 'SELECT'
    + 'COALESCE(SUM("month_value"), 0) AS month_value'
    + 'FROM "customer_products"'
    + 'WHERE "active" = true'
    + 'AND "customer_id" = :customerId'
    + ') src'
    + 'WHERE "id" = :customerId', [customerId]))
  .update({
    month_value: 'src.month_value',
    modified: 'NOW()',
});
```